# Keyboard not working, But works on a different Laptop

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, keyboard, lenovo-laptop

I have Lenovo G500s (Non touch). My Keyboard is not working. let me explain. Me and my friend have the same laptop. My keyboard is working on his laptop but not on mine. His keyboard is working fine on my laptop. (Here Keyboard means internal laptop keyboard not USB).

Both using Lenovo + Win 8.1. Already tried Driver re-Installation and restore Laptop to back point.

Try to Understand by this Diagram.

```
____________________________________________________________________
1 Laptop (mine)                       2 Laptop (friend's)
  1.Keyboard-not working               2.Keyboard-working                              
  2.keyboard-working                   1.Keyboard-working  
____________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: I dont see any question here. Looks more like self diagnosis since you added a tag `Hardware-failure`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean it....
I don't know what happened..<br/>If its hardware failure then why friend's keyboard is working on my laptop.<br/>And else if its keyboard failure then why my keyboard is working on his laptop

Comment: What is the make and model of the keyboard?

Comment: LENOVO G500s there are two model no's  MODEL NO -T6E1-US        Model no -MP-12U7

Comment: Opening a case with Lenovo will probably be your best bet.

Comment: SOLVED 

I cut the small part on the head of the connector .Its corrade (rub down) .
Thanks for help...(see that connector here https://goo.gl/RrXmjd  img source inernet)